# Add .slideUp() and .slideDown() to search results?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jquery sieve script to search in my divs. It works fine, but I want to add a jquery animation for showing the results.

So, if I type something in the searchbox, divs without a hit should .slideUp(). If i clean the searchbox the hidden divs should .slideDown(). Is that possible? If yes, how? I am not very good at jquery.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/UZ2B4/2/)

Thx for help.

```
/*!
* jQuery Sieve v0.3.0 (2013-04-04)
* http://rmm5t.github.io/jquery-sieve/
* Copyright (c) 2013 Ryan McGeary; Licensed MIT
*/ (function () {
var $;

$ = jQuery;

$.fn.sieve = function (options) {
    var compact;
    compact = function (array) {
        var item, _i, _len, _results;
        _results = [];
        for (_i = 0, _len = array.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            item = array[_i];
            if (item) {
                _results.push(item);
            }
        }
        return _results;
    };
    return this.each(function () {
        var container, searchBar, settings;
        container = $(this);
        settings = $.extend({
            searchInput: null,
            searchTemplate: "<div><label>Search: <input type='text'></label></div>",
            itemSelector: "tbody tr",
            textSelector: null,
            toggle: function (item, match) {
                return item.toggle(match);
            },
            complete: function () {}
        }, options);
        if (!settings.searchInput) {
            searchBar = $(settings.searchTemplate);
            settings.searchInput = searchBar.find("input");
            container.before(searchBar);
        }
        return settings.searchInput.on("keyup.sieve change.sieve", function () {
            var items, query;
            query = compact($(this).val().toLowerCase().split(/\s+/));
            items = container.find(settings.itemSelector);
            items.each(function () {
                var cells, item, match, q, text, _i, _len;
                item = $(this);
                if (settings.textSelector) {
                    cells = item.find(settings.textSelector);
                    text = cells.text().toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    text = item.text().toLowerCase();
                }
                match = true;
                for (_i = 0, _len = query.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                    q = query[_i];
                    match && (match = text.indexOf(q) >= 0);
                }
                return settings.toggle(item, match);
            });
            return settings.complete();
        });
    });
};

}).call(this);


$(function () {
var searchTemplate = "<label style='width:100%;'>Search: <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='search' style='width:80%;'></label>"
$(".div-sieve").sieve({
    searchTemplate: searchTemplate,
    itemSelector: "div",
    complete: function () {
    var visible = $('.div-sieve>div:visible').size();
        if(visible){
            $(".noresults").hide();
        }
        else{$(".noresults").show();}
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice the setting `toggle`? That's where you define how an element is shown/hidden depending on if it matches or not. Your current function makes use of the jQuery `.toggle(show)` method, which simply hides and shows depending on the boolean value `show` - you can use something just a tad bit more sophisticated to get your desired results:

```
toggle: function(item, match) {
    return match ? item.slideDown() : item.slideUp();
}
```

Does [this edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UZ2B4/3/) behave as you like?

Comment: Wow, that was a really fast and great support, but there is a little bug - if you type "aa" in the searchbox, the "noresults" will not appear ;(. Only if you type "aaa".

Comment: Ah, that one took me a little while to figure out. The problem is how you define when the box should be visible; the check is performed instantly, and not when the animations have finished. Either formulate a criteria that's not based on the size of the contained `div`s, or call the `sieve`s `complete` function as a callback to `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`.

Comment: @Snatch: I'm unable to quickly find an easy way to do this, but the trick is that you must either delay the checking of your criteria until the animations have actually finished (otherwise `size()` will still be `> 0`) OR have a criteria that's not dependent on the size of the objects in the list, that determines if the list is empty or not.

Comment: I tried my best with "delay", but also with no success ;(. As well I was not able to modify the script like the "empty" way ...